# Default values of OperationRetrySettings for default communication proxy

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When I create a proxy to my service like this:

```
ServiceProxy.Create<IMyService>(new Uri("fabric:/MyApplication/MyService"));
```

1. What values will OperationRetrySettings instance has?
2. Will there be any logic in default TryHandleException implementation?
3. Will any logic related to retrying in case of exceptions even be involved in case of mentioned code?
4. Is there a way to adjust retrying in case of exception logic, change values of default OperationRetrySettings?

I use FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener.

Comment: Maybe someone could correct my answer or provide more precise information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ServiceProxy.Create uses a default ServiceProxyFactory.

It is created with the default OperationRetrySettings which are documented here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt711955.aspx

The default ServiceProxyFactory also uses the default service removing client factory; FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactory.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicefabric.services.remoting.fabrictransport.client.fabrictransportserviceremotingclientfactory.fabrictransportserviceremotingclientfactory.aspx

Following the remarks on this documentation, you can see that it uses ServiceRemotingExeptionHandler which is described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicefabric.services.remoting.client.serviceremotingexceptionhandler.aspx

Comment: Just a small note: I noticed that If I throw a `TimeoutException`, then the method gets called again more than 10 times. That's the reason of my doubts about default `OperationRetrySettings`.

Comment: Are you throwing timeout exception from service implementation code and what is the version of the SDK?

Comment: yes, I'm throwing the exception from a stateless service. When I call the method with exception, I will enter it once and then 11 more times. SDK 2.1.150.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my observations, which, definitely, do not cover all the questions completely because there is not so much information:

1. Some defaults. At least `DefaultMaxRetryCount` is 10 and 2 seconds on each backoff interval. I found these values by instantiating `FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactory` and passing custom `IExceptionHandler`. Probably, this property even has no meaning if you are using default `ServiceProxyFactory` or `ServiceProxy`.
2. Looks like yes. I didn't find the exact default `IExceptionHandler` which is used in proxy and factory, but noticed numerous retries in case if I throw an `TimeoutException` exception in a service. Probably, logic of `ActorRemotingExceptionHandler` and `ServiceRemotingExceptionHandler` is used by default.
3. Yes.
4. Yes. You need to instantiate `ServiceProxyFactory` or `ActorProxyFactory`, passing there `IServiceRemotingClientFactory` implementation (for example, `FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactory`), specifying `OperationRetrySettings` and `IExceptionHandler`, passing as an exception handler your own implementation.